# Visual studio c# timer does not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

When the button is clicked, I want the color of the button to change to black after 5 seconds, but I just can't get it worked. I've already set the timer's interval to 5000 and Enabled to true in the property.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();

            button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What timer are you using? You should be using a windows.Forms.Timer.   It looks like you have added it in design time, make sure that the action that you want to delay is in the Tick Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best soultion would be ,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
            MyTimer.Interval = 4000; 
            MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
            MyTimer.Start();

        }

        private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.Black;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the color to change to black, and stay that way, after `5 seconds`, you need to place the assignment of `button1.BackColor` in the `timer1_Tick` event handler. Also, don't forget to stop the timer from ticking.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
      timer1.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        timer1.Stop();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Interval = 5000;
        timer1.Start();


    }
}
```

You have to place the trigger of the button's black backcolor on the timer's tick event.

Comment: I guess a `timer1.Stop();` put into Tick event will be great

Comment: In the winforms timer, enabling it and starting both do the same thing.

Comment: I agree. This is to ensure that the timer would tick only once :) Will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

write the color change code inside timer_tick event

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
      timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```